# How to focus for a button after enter key in angular

Tags: html, angular

Suppose that I have the below form in an angular component. How do I focus on the Log in button after clicking on enter key?

```
<form class="mt-4" #contactform="ngForm">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="" [(ngModel)]="model.eMail" required>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="" [(ngModel)]="model.password" required>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" (click)="onClickSend(contactform)">Log in</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Clear</button>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the login button to type "submit" - and the enter key will trigger it.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" (click)="onClickSend(contactform)">Log in</button>
```

You can also use ngSubmit on the form tag instead of click:

```
<form class="mt-4" #contactform="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onClickSend(contactform)">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Log in</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working. Is there any other way to achieve this without changing the button type for submit?

Comment: What would you like to achieve by that?

Comment: Suppose that there are two forms and two submit buttons. They are loading on same page. When pressing enter key, how do we exactly focus on the specific submit button?

Comment: As far as I know, the focused button will be the submit button of the form that is focused at the moment.